# Emoji reactions on bot's own message in separate channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a bot in Discord.js.
It should listen for its command being used, delete the message with the command, and post in a separate channel the command message's args.

For example, if I sent the bot `-say Stack Overflow is a good place to get help` it will post in the channel `#said-and-repeated` 'Stack Overflow is a good place to get help'. The problem is it needs to react with two emojis so the users can vote whether it's a good tip or not.

---

Code:

```js
var textToEcho = args.join(" ");
        if(args.length === 0){
            message.reply('you need to add a `message` to use this command!!');
        } else {
            message.delete();
            Client.channels.cache.get('where it will send the message').send(textToEcho).then(message => {
                message.react("emoji");
                message.react("emoji");
            }
        }
```

---

But this doesn't work, and I can't see what's wrong with it. I know that custom emojis need to be written slightly differently, but the bot only reacts with two default emojis: the check and the cross.

Comment: I still cant understand what's the problem. is it not reacting with the custom emoji? please state the error.

Comment: Do you have the actual unicode emoji instead of `emoji`?

Comment: The emoji's are unicode, but that is irrelevant, I know that I need to use the ID if it's custom @PerplexingParadox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reacting in Discord.js is completely different from sending emojis.

**To react with local emoji:-**

```
message.react("")

// Don't use emoji name, use emoji symbol instead.
```

**To react with custom emoji:-**

```
message.react("emojiID here")
```

Also you said, you want to react to bot's message. So this thing is correct but, you are instructing to react to user's message i.e. `*message*.react`.

Here what you need is, this:-

```
//We declare that botMessage is bot's message send to channel

 let botMessage = await Client.channels.cache.get('where it will send the message').send(textToEcho).then{

   // We react here...
  await botMessage.react('emojiID or symbol');
  await botMessage.react('emojiID or symbol');

}
```

*If you need any other help, tell me in comment and ping me.*

Comment: thanks, this isn't the exact result expected, but thanks to the await functions I was able to sort it out

Comment: Welcome! It would be good if you tell, what exactly fixed your problem so that i can update my answer for people who have same problems.

Comment: The await function worked for me, precisely as the top two just show how to add a reaction, not caring about what message it is. I needed it to await then send the reaction on the message the bot itself sent, so the last one worked.

Comment: oh, I had this same problem once and had to crawl the whole web to solve the same issue lol.